# dividing the time slots and displaying them

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am converting seconds into hours minutes and seconds.

and method is as follows

```
for (int i=0; i<24; i++) {

    int remain = 60/6;
    int hrs = i;
    for (int j=0; j<6; j++) {
        if (remain == 60 ) {
        remain=0;
        NSLog(@"%d:%d",hrs+1,remain);
        if (hrs==24) {
        NSLog(@"%d:%d",hrs,remain);
        }
        }else{
        NSLog(@"%d:%d",hrs,remain);
        remain = remain+10;
        }

    }
}
```

I want to divide the time (24 hrs ) into slots of 10 minutes that me i need to display 
00:10 ,00:20,.....up to 23:40,23:50 .

but i want to display the time slots with 00:10 to 23:50  but the out put is as follows 0:10
simply need display double zeros

0:20
0:30
0:40
0:50
1:0
1:10
1:20
1:30
1:40
1:50
2:0
2:10
2:20
2:30
2:40
2:50
3:0

Comment: You haven't said what problem you are having with this code. I can make a couple of guesses, but it would be nice to hear it from you. Also, the code in your question is to transform a number of seconds held in a string into a formatted number of hours, minutes and seconds, not to split up a 24 hour period into time slots.

Comment: what problem are you facing in dividing the slots ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a different format for displaying leading zeros. This will display at least 2 digits for hours, filling up with 0 if the digits would be less:

`NSLog(@"%02d:%d",hrs, remain)`